# My Toast message not showing properly

Tags: android, radio-button, toast

I'm making a program for Android to display `Toast messages` using `RadioButton`,

In my program:

`Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //here i'm using "rd.toString()", I tried to be used "rd.getText()" but it's showing an error.`

now in Display it's showing [this](http://postimg.org/image/frezgxre5/) error.

here is my full source code to display radio button, please help how to fix this issue?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.lesson08;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListener();
    }

    public void addListener() {
        final RadioGroup rd=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.sex);
        Button disp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.display);
        disp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                int selectID=rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectID);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
02-11 07:20:22.358: I/Choreographer(1575): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-11 07:20:24.778: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-11 07:20:24.870: D/(1575): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7daa1e8, tid 1575
02-11 07:20:24.918: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-11 07:20:24.962: D/libEGL(1575): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-11 07:20:25.202: W/EGL_genymotion(1575): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-11 07:20:25.242: E/OpenGLRenderer(1575): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-11 07:20:25.242: E/OpenGLRenderer(1575): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-11 07:20:25.662: E/OpenGLRenderer(1575): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-11 07:20:25.666: D/OpenGLRenderer(1575): Enabling debug mode 0
02-11 07:20:25.918: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 4% free 2926K/3044K, paused 15ms, total 17ms
02-11 07:20:57.814: D/libEGL(1634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-11 07:20:57.910: D/(1634): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7d8c188, tid 1634
02-11 07:20:58.002: D/libEGL(1634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-11 07:20:58.058: D/libEGL(1634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-11 07:20:58.290: W/EGL_genymotion(1634): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-11 07:20:58.298: E/OpenGLRenderer(1634): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-11 07:20:59.006: E/OpenGLRenderer(1634): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-11 07:20:59.010: D/OpenGLRenderer(1634): Enabling debug mode 0
02-11 07:20:59.362: D/dalvikvm(1634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 5% free 2919K/3044K, paused 14ms, total 17ms
02-11 07:22:59.346: D/libEGL(1712): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-11 07:22:59.370: D/(1712): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7da6fa8, tid 1712
02-11 07:22:59.462: D/libEGL(1712): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-11 07:22:59.466: D/libEGL(1712): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-11 07:22:59.938: W/EGL_genymotion(1712): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-11 07:23:01.170: E/OpenGLRenderer(1712): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-11 07:23:01.502: E/OpenGLRenderer(1712): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-11 07:23:01.518: D/OpenGLRenderer(1712): Enabling debug mode 0
02-11 07:23:02.314: D/dalvikvm(1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 5% free 2899K/3032K, paused 75ms, total 77ms
```

Comment: Gettext is the right method  which error shows up when you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you like to display `RadioButton` text which is selected. So you can use following code.

```
RadioButton selectedRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectID);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedRadioButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: still showing an error I tried this..will I have to `import` something for that?

Comment: No. you don't need to import any thing.. but i think  whatever you are getting error is not in scope of this.. its all about libraries which you are used in your application..

Comment: I still don't understand [here](http://postimg.org/image/644i59fw3/) is showing an error

Comment: @user3284233, my friend. What i have provided answer is for `RadioButton` and you are using `RadioGroup`. It doesn't have that method. Please recheck my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah it's working now ...thanks..i was using `rd` instead `rb`...:p thnks anyway..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectID);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rb.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`rb.toString()` returns the name of the radio group instance.. If you use `getText()` first. It returns the text and converts it to a string.

Comment: Yes i think you should use this answer like the rest is saying

Answer (score 0):

change like this

```
RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectID);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rb.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in place of this

```
RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectID);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectID);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, rb.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```